# MIX 11 knockout code sample and my mistake

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I type code sample from this video:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08

But it is not work. Where is typo or another mistake? 
My source copy available at http://jsfiddle.net/fFedK/

HTML:

```
<span data-bind="text:firstName"></span><br /><br />
<input data-bind="value:firstName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /><br /><br />

<span data-bind="text:lastName"></span><br /><br /><br />
<input data-bind="value:lastName, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /><br /><br />

<span data-bind="text:fullName"></span><br /><br />

<h2>Friends</h2>

<div data-bind="template: 'friendsTemplate'"></div>

<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <ul>
        {{each(index, friend) friends}}
            <li> ${ friend.name } </li>
        {{/each}}

    </ul>

</script>​
```

Script code:

```
function friend(name) {
    return {
        name: ko.observable(name)
    }
}


var viewModel = {
    firstName : ko.observable("Mike"),
    lastName : ko.observable("Rassel"),

    friends : ko.observableArray([new friend("Steve"), new friend("Annie")])
}

//viewModel.fullName = ko.computed(function () { return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName(); }, viewModel);





ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed your jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qHhEV/4/

The example was using the old jQuery tmpl syntax which has been largely deprecated so I've updated it to use knockout native templates:

```
<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <ul>
        <!-- ko foreach: friends -->
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>     
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>

</script>
```

There was also a few syntax errors that I have fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The example has a dependency on jquery and jquery-tmpl libraries.

So your page has to load js libraries in the following order:
1. Jquery
2. Jquery-tmpl
3. Knockout.js

I've linked to the following fiddle with it working.  No code change was required: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfFjn/1/)

But yes, as pointed in the other answer, there are newer templating mechanisms which should be used.  The jquery-tmpl library is no longer in development.

You can avoid templates all together with the foreach binding.  Overall I think this is more concise:  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LfFjn/2/)

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: friends">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```